# how to get all connections from paginated resolver graph ql apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo

Sorry if this question is not being worded correctly. I have a website that calls a graph ql server, and Im trying to retrieve all images for a particular user, where the graph ql server is paginating the result.

Here is my query:

```
query UserPhotos ($userId: ID) {
        user(input: { id: $userId }) {
        edges {
            node {
               id
               imageUrl
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where each `edge` implements the [connection edge specification](https://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm). This query would return to me a connection list of 50 edges, but there are more images (for a particular user, there should be like 100) to be retrieved in the graphql server. Does anyone know how I can change my query to simply get all of the images and how many images there are from the graphql server?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
query UserPhotos ($userId: ID) {
 user(input: { id: $userId }) {
     id
     imageUrl
  }
}
```

The Query you wrote is used for pagination and Ideally you should not want to create an edge with a node unless you want an opaque cursor for the purpose of pagination.

The Query I provided does not try to paginate and thus, would provide you with all your `image` Objects.

you can refer this page for better understanding: 
https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/